# In Swift, how would I reference `self` in nested timers?

Tags: swift, closures, block, self, weak

If I would nest two timers that are both properties of the class they are referenced in, would I have to call `[weak self]` in both or just the first timer block?

```swift
timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
    print(self)
    self?.timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
        print(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. Every nested closure it is better to put a weak reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't convert the `weak` reference into a strong one outside of your nested closure, the `weak` reference is passed into the nested closure, so you don't need to make it `weak` again.

So the below code is just fine:

```
timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
    print(self)
    self?.timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
        print(self)
    }
}
```

You can confirm this by the fact that you'll get the warning

> Expression implicitly coerced from 'Timers?' to 'Any'

On both `print` statements.

You always need to create a weak reference in the outer-most closure where you reference self, otherwise your outer closure will create a strong-reference cycle, so whether the inner one creates a weak reference or not won't make a difference.

This creates a strong reference cycle, since to access `timer2`, you use a strong reference to `self`.

```
timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { _ in
    print(self)
    self.timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
        print(self)
    }
}
```

As long as you convert the weak reference to a strong one using a variable with a different name, the reference to `self` will be `weak` and hence you don't need to make it `weak` again.

So the below code is also free of strong reference cycles.

```
timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    print(strongSelf)
    strongSelf.timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        print(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Converting it to a strong reference in the outside timer would mean I would have to make it weak in the nested timer though?

Comment: And what about _not_ weakening it in the outer timer but in the nested one. Is that okay? `timer1 { timer2 { [weak self] in } }`

Comment: @Patia1999 check my updated answer, included the answer and code samples for both scenarios